# fullcalendar, how to limit the number of events per day in the month view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have many events on a day, and it works as expected but now looking at the month view, my calendar grid is much taller that expected.  I'd like to hide some of these events from the month view, like a summary with a visual que that there are more on this day than can be shown.

I can use eventRender and return false, but i would like to know how many events are on a given day, so i can limit the rendering to about 4, then perhaps i would add an event that says " more ... "

So the question may be : how to count the events on a given date ?

or is this more like a feature request to expose a max counter for month view ?

thanks

Comment: This is a good question indeed, I am having the same problem as well. See if API documentation will help you : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

Answer (score 5):

As of FullCalendar 2.1.0, this feature is included, just use:

```
$('#calendarBlock').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: true
    [...]
});
```

Demo: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-2.1.0-beta2/demos/agenda-views.html

Documentation: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar requirement and was thinking of doing something like this:

in json feed, I would return special events that contain a count of events for each day.

Using appropriate full calendar eventRender callback, I would only display these special total count events depending on view by returning false in eventRender() for any events I don't want to see.

I haven't implemented this yet, but perhaps it can be a valid avenue.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

currently not possible. see feature request:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304

Comment: The feature request linked has now been updated with this comment "Four years later I have finally implemented this feature. It is part of v2.1.0-beta2. Please try the beta and post any feedback. More information on the beta release here: http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2014/07/fullcalendar-210-beta.html " The full comment: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304#c137

Answer (score 1):

This buggy (mostly abandoned) plugin does <del>exactly</del> what you're asking for.  Check it out, and feel free to contribute.  **Warning:**  It is a hack, but fullcalendar itself has an API that needs a lot of work.  Most of the important parts are trapped in a closure, which makes it very difficult to extend.  There really is no way to accomplish this without hackery, unless you want to edit the plugin's source code.

That being said, this is the closest I have found to what you are asking for:  https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar/tree/view-more

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take much effort on taking the total count of events.
I have got a simple way to count total events on my fullCalendar. In the `eventAfterAllRender` , write something like this,

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
                    var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                    var countevents = 0;
                    if( allevents.length ) {
                        countevents = countevents + allevents.length;
                    }
                    if(!countevents) {
                        // alert('event count is'+countevents);
                        console.log('event count is',countevents);
                    }
                }
```

-where `calendar` is my calendar #

This is all my way of doing. I am taking left from here. But I am sure, it is not that harder if you try something on the `loading: function()` of the fullCalendar to limit the number of events according to your wish.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
function(start, end, callback) {
                var viewName = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView');
                var startTime = Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000);
                var endTime = Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000);
                MyWebService.MyWebMethod.GetEventsByView(startTime, endTime, viewName.name,
                    function(args) {
                        callback(args);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        var e = error;
                    }
                );
            }
```

Here the `GetEventsByView` method returns a grouped set for month view and detailed set for agendaWeek and day views. But for this to work correctly, I had to set `lazyFetching:false` for the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like this

Css:

```
        .MaxHght
        {
        height:16px;
        }
        .viewMore
        {
        float:right;
        color: rgb(219, 104, 28);
        cursor:pointer;
        }
```

plugin code

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                   $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
               },
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                element.qtip({
                   content: event.QText,

                   position: {
                       my: 'CenterBottom',
                           at:'TopCenter'

                   },
                   style: {
                       tip: 'bottomMiddle'

                   }
               });
               $(element).removeClass('MaxHght');
               if (view.name == 'month') {

                       $(element).addClass('MaxHght');
                   var year = event.start.getFullYear(), month = event.start.getMonth() + 1, date = event.start.getDate();
                   var result = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + (date < 10 ? '0' + date : date);
                   $(element).addClass(result);
                   var ele = $('td[data-date="' + result + '"]'),count=$('.' + result).length;
                   $(ele).find('.viewMore').remove();
                   if ( count> 3) {
                       $('.' + result + ':gt(2)').remove();                          
                       $(ele).find('.fc-day-number').after('<a class="viewMore"> More</a>');

                   } 
               }

           },
           eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
               if (view.name == 'month') {
                   $('td.fc-day').each(function () {
                       var EventCount = $('.' + $(this).attr('data-date')).length;
                       if (EventCount == 0)
                           $(this).find('.viewMore').remove();
                   });
               }
           },
```