# Fullcalendar, required files for limit number events per day with view more/ more button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am working in fullcalendar view functionlity. I am using ,

**fullcalendar.css**

**fullcalendar.min.js.**

My code is,

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      editable: true,           
      events:curEvents
  });
```

Its working fine. But, if I pass more data into 'curevents' means, month view height goes to very long. So I like to add **'limit events'** concept with **'viewmore/more'** option/link to display data via popup box (or) when I click the 'viewmore' option it will redirect to day view. 
So I tried some code,

```
$('#calendar').limitEvents(4);
```

from help of below link =>

[fullcalendar, how to limit the number of events per day in the month view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575538/fullcalendar-how-to-limit-the-number-of-events-per-day-in-the-month-view)

But height of the month view only aligned.View more button not yet displayed.So I want, name of the files for working this view more button functionality. 
If you give deep code explanation means, its more helpful for me. 
View more button not yet show and below code not limit the events also.

```
$('#calendar').limitEvents(4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

With the new build v2.1.0-beta2 Launch 17 days ago **Arshaw** did the following

> RESOLVED ISSUES:
>
> - Max events with "more..." link (304)
> - Don't fire eventMouseover/eventMouseout while dragging/resizing (1297)
>
> NEW OPTIONS:
>
> - eventLimit
> - eventLimitClick
> - eventLimitText
> - dayPopoverFormat

[Source](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta2)

So, you can do the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    lang: 'en',
    eventLimit: true, // If you set a number it will hide the itens
    eventLimitText: "Something" // Default is `more` (or "more" in the lang you pick in the option)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michel. I will use this in my new project

Comment: How can we limit to a fixed number?