# Full Calendar: Limit events per day in one cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to limit events per one cell on the bootstrap calendar as appears in attached image?
I want to show it as 2 events and "... X more" label in case there's more than 2 events with the same date and prevent stretching the whole calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

With the new build v2.1.0-beta2 Launch 17 days ago Arshaw did the following

> RESOLVED ISSUES:
>
> Max events with "more..." link (304) Don't fire
>   eventMouseover/eventMouseout while dragging/resizing (1297) NEW
>   OPTIONS:
>
> eventLimit event
>   LimitClick 
>   eventLimitText 
>   dayPopoverFormat

Source

So, you can do the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    lang: 'en',
    eventLimit: true, // If you set a number it will hide the itens
    eventLimitText: "Something" // Default is `more` (or "more" in the lang you pick in the option)
});
```

tooked from: [Fullcalendar, required files for limit number events per day with view more/ more button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063699/fullcalendar-required-files-for-limit-number-events-per-day-with-view-more-mor)

Answer (score 9):

In v5.0.0-beta.2 the `eventLimit` option did not seem to work but the `dayMaxEvents` option did.

Source: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/d3a2b13db43cfe9a450091776da3be25a0ca15c0/packages/daygrid/src/TableRow.tsx#L40

Example:

```js
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  dayMaxEvents: 3 // Can also be set as a boolean
});
```

Comment: For v5.x this is the correct answer. It is also mentioned in their release notes that the eventLimit was replaced: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Answer (score 4):

If it's the month view, the configuration should be something like this:

```
 eventLimit: true,
  views: {
     month: {
       eventLimit: 3
     }
 }
```

Also if there are several events, adding a scroll bar could be helpful:

```
.fc-more-popover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 14%;
}
```

Comment: But, if I have 5 events in my day view , 5 events in my month view and eventLimit as 2 for my month configuration, then I get +8 more in my month view which is invalid. Because, I have only 5 events in my month view so it should display +3 more instead of +8 more...

Answer (score 0):

Set it as

```
eventLimitText: function (numEvents) {
                        return "YourCustomText";
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit,

You can use the following code and upgrade it, depending on your goal:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  eventLimit: true, // for all non-TimeGrid views
    views: {
      timeGrid: {
      eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
    }
  }
});
```

In this case in the calendar will be shown only a few elements but at the bottom of each day will be a link `+x more`, with `x` representing the total number of your records for the current day which pops up a modal window with the rest of the information.

I hope I was helpful!

**Edit:**

Apparently `eventLimit: true` was enough for default functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using FullCalendar v5 and want to limit events in month view, add below option -

```
views: {
    dayGridMonth: {
        dayMaxEventRows: 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a code so that it will not allow more that 3 event in day cell.

```
drop: function(t, a) {
                var n = e(this).data("eventObject"),
                    r = e.extend({}, n);
                    var date = new Date(t._d);
                    var year = date.getFullYear();
                    var rawMonth = parseInt(date.getMonth()) + 1;
                    var month = rawMonth < 10 ? '0' + rawMonth : rawMonth;
                    var rawDay = parseInt(date.getDate()) + 1;
                    var day = rawDay < 10 ? '0' + rawDay : rawDay; 
                    var dropdate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;

                var eventId = '';
                var totalEvents = e('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', function(eventObj){
                    eventId = eventObj._id;
                    var date = new Date(eventObj.start._d);
                    var year = date.getFullYear();
                    var rawMonth = parseInt(date.getMonth()) + 1;
                    var month = rawMonth < 10 ? '0' + rawMonth : rawMonth;
                    var rawDay = parseInt(date.getDate()) + 1;
                    var day = rawDay < 10 ? '0' + rawDay : rawDay; 
                    var newdate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;

                    if (dropdate == newdate) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).length;

                if( totalEvents > 3 ){
                    e('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventId);
                }

            },
```